# How do I access routes of Rails application without loading the environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I am trying to access `Rails.application.routes` in a Capistrano receipt.
It's working when requiring Rails and the whole environment `require 'config/environment'`

Can I require more specific files for accessing the application's routes without loading the environment? It takes so much time to load.

Background information:

The directory for storing the picture's cache of the isolated and mounted engine is named like the mount-path:

```
/public/myMountedEngine/pictures/...
```

I want to read the mount-path of the mounted isolated engine for symlinking the nested pictures folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to load the `config/application.rb` at least to get the routes, so you'll get something like this:

```
require "./config/application"
MyApp::Application.routes
```